# Laravel DB facade how to express LIKE

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-facade

I have a query:

```
DB::select('select * from student where name like "%?%" or description like "%?%"',[$keyword,$keyword])
```

but I got empty result, which shouldn't be. I think it might take "?" instead of my keyword, how should I modify it?

Answer (score 4):

You might wanna use that statement like this.

```
DB::table('students')->where('name','LIKE',"%$keyword%")->orWhere('description','LIKE',"%$keyword%")->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way as well:

```
$result = DB::table('students')->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
    $query->orWhere('name', 'like', "%".$keyword."%");
    $query->orWhere('description', 'like', "%".$keyword."%");
})->get();
```